# Files with quotes, spaces causing bad behavior from xargs

Tags: bash, shell, sh, xargs

I want to `find` some files and calculate the `shasum` by using a pipe command.

```
find . -type f | xargs shasum
```

But there are files withe quotes in my directory, for example the file named

```
file with "special" characters.txt
```

The pipe output look like this:

```
user@home ~ $ find . -type f | xargs shasum
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  ./empty1.txt
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  ./empty2.txt
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  ./empty3.txt
shasum: ./file: 
shasum: with: No such file or directory
shasum: special: No such file or directory
shasum: characters.txt: No such file or directory
25ea78ccd362e1903c4a10201092edeb83912d78  ./file1.txt
25ea78ccd362e1903c4a10201092edeb83912d78  ./file2.txt
```

The quotes within the filename makes problems.

How can I tell `shasum` to process the files correctly?

Comment: Are you sure you need `xargs`? `find . -type f -exec shasum {} \;`

Comment: @chepner, ...well, with `-exec ... \;`, there's performance benefit to `xargs` since we're able to start fewer `shasum` instances. That said, since `-exec ... {} +` is available, yah, not much point.

Comment: Here, I'm pretty sure the overhead of starting `shasum` is negligible compared to the cost of actually computing the checksum for a single file.

Comment: If the files are large ("not tiny"?), sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short explanation is that `xargs` is widely considered broken-by-design, *unless* using extensions to the standard that disable its behavior of trying to parse and honor quote and escaping content in its input. See [the `xargs` section of UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-) for more details.

---

#### Using NUL Delimited Streams

On a system with GNU or modern BSD extensions (including MacOS X), you can (and should) NUL-delimit the output from `find`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 shasum --
```

---

#### Using `find -exec`

That said, you can do even better by getting `xargs` out of the loop entirely in a way that's fully compliant with modern (~2006) POSIX:

```
find . -type f -exec shasum -- '{}' +
```

Note that the `--` argument specifies to `shasum` that all future arguments are filenames. If you'd used `find * -type f ...`, then you could have a result starting with a dash; using `--` ensures that this result isn't interpreted as a set of options.

---

#### Using Newline Delimiters (And Security Risks Thereof)

If you have GNU xargs, but *don't* have the option of a NUL-delimited input stream, then `xargs -d $'\n'` (in shells such as bash with ksh extensions) will avoid the quoting and escaping behavior:

```
xargs -d $'\n' shasum -- <files.txt
```

However, this is suboptimal, because newline literals are actually possible inside filenames, thus making it impossible to distinguish between a newline that separates two names and a newline that is part of an actual name. Consider the following scenario:

```
mkdir -p ./file.txt$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'/
touch ./file.txt$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'file.txt file.txt
find . -type f | xargs -d $'\n' shasum --
```

This will have output akin to the following:

```
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  ./file.txt
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  ./file.txt
c0c71bac843a3ec7233e99e123888beb6da8fbcf  /etc/passwd
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  file.txt
```

...thus allowing an attacker who can control filenames to cause a shasum for an arbitrary file *outside* the intended directory structure to be added to your output.